# Is it safe to copy cassandra snapshot files over sstable files in a running node?

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

Edited after reading nodetool tagged questions.

We take snapshots of our single node cassandra database daily. If I want to restore a snapshot either on that node, or on our staging server which is running a different instance of cassandra, my understanding is I have to:

1. nodetool disablegossip
2. nodetool disablebinary
3. nodetool drain
4. Copy the sstable files from the snapshot directories to the sstable directories under the keyspace directory.
5. Run nodetool refresh on each table.
6. Enable binary & gossip.

Is this sufficient to safely bring the snapshot sstable files in without cassandra overwriting them while I'm doing the refresh?

What is the opposite of nodetool drain?

Another edit: What about sstableloader? Should I use that instead? If so, how? I looked at the "documentation" and am none the wiser.

Comment: why not simply stop node, copy files & start again? if you disable gossip & binary, your node is effectively down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps you outlined isn't quite right. You don't shutdown Cassandra and you shouldn't just copy the files on top of the existing SSTables.

At a high level, the steps to restore table snapshots on a node are:

1. `TRUNCATE` the table you want to restore (will remove the SSTables from the data directories).
2. Copy the SSTables from `data/ks_name/table-UUID/snapshots/snapshot_name` subdirectory into the "live" data directory `data/ks_name/table-UUID`.
3. Run `nodetool refresh -- ks_name table_name`.

You will need to repeat these steps for each application table you want to restore. NOTE: Do *NOT* restore system tables, only application tables.

The detailed steps are documented in [Restoring from a snapshot in Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/operations/opsBackupSnapshotRestore.html).

To restore a snapshot into another cluster, I prefer to refer to this as "cloning". The procedure for cloning snapshots to another cluster depends on whether the source and destination clusters have **identical configuration**.

If both source and destination clusters are identical, follow the steps I documented here -- https://community.datastax.com/questions/4534/. I've explained what **identical configuration** means in this post.

If they are *not identical*, follow the steps I documented here -- https://community.datastax.com/questions/4477/. Cheers!

Comment: What is to stop new data getting written during this sequence? I truncate a table, that removes the sstable files, but then between steps 2 and 3 I can't see why new data could not be written causing some sort of trouble.

Comment: Even the datastax documentation is vague - I had read it already.

It makes no mention draining, it says you "may" need to truncate the table and then immediately says this is "usually" necessary. While those two things are not exlusive first of all it sounds like you probably don't need to truncate, then says you probably do!

It makes no mention of how the table is protected against new data being written after the truncate.

Comment: The cluster will accept writes unless you shutdown the app -- it's your choice. `TRUNCATE` depends on what you're trying to achieve. If you do NOT truncate, any deletes already issued means the data will not be returned. For example, if `DELETE ... WHERE pk = 'alice'` then restoring the partition `pk = 'alice'` won't be returned by `SELECT ... WHERE pk = 'alice'`. Cheers!